# I have two subscriptions Pay-As-You-Go & Azure subscriptions on my profile. What is the difference and do I need to use both?

Tags: azure

I have two subscriptions Pay-As-You-Go & Azure subscriptions on my profile. What is the difference and do I need to use both? Or what is the best way for this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no subscription named as Azure subscription. See the list of [Azure offers](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/support/legal/offer-details/) for
details.

In the Azure portal click on 'All services' > subscription tab you will see the subscriptions you've access to.

Also, refer to this link - https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Azure/Understanding-Azure-Account-Subscription-and-Directory/m-p/34800 to understand Azure account, subscription, Azure AD and Resource groups briefly explained by Daniel Martins.

Hope that helps!